# Kendo UI issue with removing file

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">
     <input name="files" id="files" type="file/>
</div>
```

And my javascript/jquery trying to remove file when it is not of certain extension.

It does not appear to be working when I want to remove. The rest is working as expected.

I do not want save to be initiated because I don't want it to save yet.

If silly please ignore. This is my first encounter with Kendo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            autoUpload: true,
            //saveUrl: "save",
            removeUrl: "remove",
            withCredentials: false
        },
        select: onSelect,
    });
});

function onSelect(e) {
    var files = e.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var uid = files[i].uid;
        var entry = $(".k-file[data-uid='" + uid + "']");
        alert(files[i].name);
        if (files[i].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() != 'pdf') {
            alert('Only documents are allowed.');
            //$("#files").data("kendoUpload").removeFileByUid(uid);
            //entry.remove();

            removeFile(uid, entry);
        }
    }
}

function removeFile(uid, entry) {
    alert(uid);
   // entry.remove();
   // $(uid).remove();
   // $('#' + uid).remove();
    document.getElementById(''+uid).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in your select by canceling the event.

```
function onSelect(e) {
    var files = e.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var uid = files[i].uid;
        var entry = $(".k-file[data-uid='" + uid + "']");
        alert(files[i].name);
        if (files[i].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() != 'pdf') {
            alert('Only documents are allowed.');
            //$("#files").data("kendoUpload").removeFileByUid(uid);
            //entry.remove();

            //removeFile(uid, entry);
            e.preventDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still keeps adding the file.  and onSelect is throwing error.

Comment: Oh, doh!. I see the select fires when a files is browsed to and selected, whereas, the upload fires when the file is about to be uploaded.

Comment: Can you try the updated code I posted above to stop event propagation in you select function?

Comment: So I used my code and just added `e.preventDefault();` and that did it :) .. if yours was onSelect, it would have worked too I assume. Can you update your answer please?